# Cannot SpyOn a primitive value; undefined given. Jest when trying to mock useParams()?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

I am trying to create a unit test for my Profile component that calls the userService, and displays the user's information in a profile.

To do this I am using React-Testing-Library but am experiencing an issue when I am trying to mock the useParam() hook call executed within the Profile component.

This is necessary because the Profile() Component ordinarily passes in the user id of the user to generate a profile for through React Router dynamic link path variable.

Test:

```
import React from 'react'

// import API mocking utilities from Mock Service Worker
import {rest} from 'msw'
import {setupServer} from 'msw/node'

// import react-testing methods
import {render, fireEvent, waitFor, screen} from '@testing-library/react'
import routeData from 'react-router';

// add custom jest matchers from jest-dom
import '@testing-library/jest-dom';

import config from "../configuration/Configuration.json";
import {Profile} from "../pages/Profile";

const userId = 1;

const server = setupServer(
    rest.get(config.URL + '/users/' + userId, (req, res, ctx) => {
        return res(ctx.json({userId: 1, email: 'testEmail@outlook.com', password: null, firstName: 'Test', lastName: 'User'}))
    }),
)

beforeAll(() => server.listen())
afterEach(() => server.resetHandlers())
afterAll(() => server.close())
beforeEach(() => jest.spyOn(routeData, 'useParams').mockReturnValue(1))

test('loads and displays profile', async () => {

    render(<Profile />)

    await waitFor(() => screen.getByRole('Profile'))

    expect(screen.getByText('testEmail@outlook.com')).toBeVisible();

})
```

Profile Component:

```
export const Profile = () => {

    //array of compatible users fetched for a user.
    const [userProfileInformation, setUserProfileInformation] = useState([]);
    const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true);

    const { userId } = useParams();

    useEffect(() => {
        getUserProfileInformation().then(() => {
            setLoading(false);
        });
    }, []);

    const getUserProfileInformation = async () => {
        const response = await UserService.getUserProfileInformation(userId)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                setUserProfileInformation(data);
            });
    }

    if (isLoading) {
        return (
            <div id="loading">
                <h2>Loading...</h2>
            </div>
        )
    }

    return (
    <div>
        <div className="profileCard">
            <h1 name='fullName'>{getFullName(userProfileInformation.firstName, userProfileInformation.lastName)}</h1>
            <h2>{userProfileInformation.email}</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
    )
}
```

Any help would be appreciated as as far as I can see online this should work, thanks.

Edit - Error:

```
Error: Cannot spyOn on a primitive value; undefined given

at ModuleMocker.spyOn 
at Object.<anonymous>
at Promise.then.completed 
at new Promise (<anonymous>)
at callAsyncCircusFn 
at _callCircusHook 
at _runTest frontend\node_modules\jest-circus\build\run.js:148:5)
at _runTestsForDescribeBlock 
at run 
at runAndTransformResultsToJestFormat
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting when running the test? Can you provide that data too?

Comment: @n1md7 I added the full error to the question but it is effectively: Error: Cannot spyOn on a primitive value; undefined given     thanks.

Comment: It says your `routeData ` is undefined. Can you console log it to verify whether your import works correctly?

Comment: @n1md7 There is no where I can put it that won't trigger an error, I even tried removing the BeforeEach and just logging routeData but the only thing it prints is a Profile page component rendered with undefined values. Thanks.